# How to Forward MJPG Webcam to Virtual Video Device using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, mjpeg, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I have a webcam that looks like this:

```
$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55fe6d48a240] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : 1920x1080 1280x720 640x480 320x240
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55fe6d48a240] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x480 320x240

$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x240                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

I created a virtual video device like this:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=20
```

I tried to forward the stream with ffmpeg using:

```
$ ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 /dev/video20
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x560fef7a8340] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 1280x720 to 640x480
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 169134.649958, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video20':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, q=2-31, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
frame=  109 fps= 32 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:03.63 bitrate=N/A dup=4 drop=0 speed=1.06x
```

However I keep ending up with the virtual device looking like this:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video20 --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

It appears to only forward YUYV format no matter what I specify in the ffmpeg command. How do I forward my webcam using mjpg so I can use the virtual device at higher resolutions?

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Done. I keep getting - The V4L2 driver changed the video from 1280x720 to 640x480

Comment: Show output of `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0`

Comment: Done. Gives same info as `v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext`

Comment: Don't know why V4L2 is changing the size. Possibly nothing to do with `ffmpeg`, but just in-case try a version from git master branch ([download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)) and run  `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f v4l2 /dev/video20`

Comment: Tried compiling from source (master branch) and unfortunately same result. Maybe it's something to do with the v4l2loopback driver?

Comment: Hey, this seems to work! `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -f v4l2 /dev/video20`

Comment: Was it changing `-s` to `-video_size`, updating `ffmpeg`, or adding `-pix_fmt yuyv422` that fixed it? (I doubt #3 because it seemed like an input problem).

Comment: Just tried the original command and even though it still says it's changing to 640x480, I get the 1280x720 when I look at the stats using v4l2-ctl. Very strange...I'll keep researching this if you want to break into a chat we can discuss further.